# JS select2 контроль заполнения

Tags: javascript, select2

В проекте использую библиотеку select2 (https://select2.org/), стоит две задачи:

1. Отслеживать ввод пользователя посимвольно (js-example-basic-single)
2. На основании введенных данных (п.1) обновлять список option (на основании запроса к онлайн сервису, эта часть в проекте уже реализована)

Какое событие в select2 отслеживает ввод символов (по аналогии addEventListener('input')). Как динамически добавлять в select2 новые значения

Comment: Вы забыли сформулировать вопрос

Comment: @Kromster, вопрос это 2 пункта, какое событие есть в select2 для отслеживания ввода символов, и каким образом можно добавлять новые значения (в документации я не нашел ослеживания ввода)

Comment: Вопрос в теле вопроса сформулируйте пожалуйста

Comment: Разве не тут https://select2.org/searching  и https://select2.org/tagging ответы на вопросы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, это то что вам нужно

```js
        $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
        $(".js-example-basic-multiple").on("select2:open", function() {
            $(".select2-search__field").on("input", function(e) {
              let value = e.target.value;
              console.log("Ввод пользователя:", value);
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
```

UPD:
Также при закрытие можно добавить

```
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").on("select2:close", function () {
  $(".select2-search__field").off("input");
});
```

По поводу массива - сложно реализовать без конкретного примера и более детального объяснения

```js
const someArr = ['I', 'love', 'JS'];

$('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({
    tags: true
});

$(".js-example-basic-multiple").on("select2:open", function () {
    $(".select2-search__field").on("input", function (e) {
        let value = e.target.value;
        console.log("Ввод пользователя:", value);

        if (value.toLowerCase() === 'gogi') {
            $('.js-example-basic-multiple').empty().select2({
                data: someArr
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
     </select>
```

1. При вводе слова gogi подгружаются значения с массива someArr;
2. .empty() - тут мы очищаем значение;
3. .select2({data: someArr}) тут добавляем новые;

Надеюсь вас правильно понял

Comment: А как в Option добавить масив значений и при необходимости очистить все значения?

Comment: @Дмитрий это уже не по контексту вопроса который вы задавали ранее, но я отпишу чуть позже минут 20-30 щас занят

Comment: @Дмитрий выше обновил свой ответ